# How to build a matrix in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Hi guys I want to build a matrix in numpy that works something like this but with different operators.

```
def build(r_start, r_stop, r_step, c_start, c_stop, c_step):
    r = np.arange(r_start, r_stop + 1, r_step)
    c = np.arange(c_start, c_stop + 1, c_step)
    ne = int(r_start != c_start)
    ret = np.empty((c.size + ne, r.size + ne), int)
    ret[0, 0] = 0
    ret[ne:, 0] = c
    ret[0, ne:] = r
    np.subtract.outer(ret[1:, 0], ret[0, 1:], out=ret[1:, 1:])
    print(ret)


build(1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1)
```

So I wanted to ask if it is possible to create a matrix in which the items of the matrix divide like an equivalent to np.add.outer but with division.

Comment: `np.divide.outer`?

Comment: yeah i have tried that but then always this occurs ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/colin/Documents/Projects/workplace/Chatbot/CB/Mathe/Matrix und Graphen/Matrix/DivMatrix.py", line 16, in <module>
    build(1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1)
  File "/Users/colin/Documents/Projects/workplace/Chatbot/CB/Mathe/Matrix und Graphen/Matrix/DivMatrix.py", line 12, in build
    np.true_divide.outer(ret[1:, 0], ret[0, 1:], out=ret[1:, 1:])
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc true_divide```

Comment: You need to change the dtype of `ret` from `int` to `float`, because the result of division is always a floating point number.